# Potential typo in Gemelin & Greene proof that compact Hausdorff spaces are normal?

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I am reading the book *Introduction to Topology* by Gamelin and Greene and I have a doubt about their proof that compact Hausdorff spaces are normal. It seems to me that there might be a typo, but I want someone to either confirm this, or explain to me why I am wrong. Firstly, we have the following lemma:

**Lemma.** Let $S$ be a compact subset of a Hausdorff space $X$. For every $x\in X\setminus S$, there exist disjoint open neighbourhoods $U$ of $x$ and $V$ of $S$.

Then, the proof is as follows:

**Theorem.** A compact Hausdorff space is normal

*Proof.* Let $S$ and $T$ be disjoint closed subsets of a compact Hausdorff space $X$. Then $S$ and $T$ are compact so by the lemma for each $x\in T$, there exist disjoint open neighbourhoods $U_x$ of $x$ and $V_x$ of $S$. Then $\{U_x\}_{x\in T}$ is a cover for $T$ so by compactness there exist $x_1,...,x_n$ such that
$$T\subset V_{x_1}\cup\, ...\cup\, V_{x_n} = V.$$
Then $U=U_{x_1}\,\cap ...\cap \,U_{x_{n}}$ and $V$ are disjoint open neighbourhoods of $S$ and $T$, respectively. $\square$

It seems to me that the definitions of $V$ and $U$ are incorrect. I believe that it should be
$$T\subset U_{x_{1}}\,\cup...\cup\, U_{x_n}=U$$ and $$V=V_{x_1}\cap ...\cap V_{x_{n}}$$
so that $U$ and $V$ are disjoint open neighbourhoods of $T$ and $S$, respectively.

Am I correct or have I made some silly oversight?

Comment: Yes, it seems that the $U$'s and $V$'s were accidentally  tranposed.